# Beginner Error with "getline"

Tags: c++, getline

this is my first time posting a question so I hope I'm getting this right. Anyways, I'm trying to create a program to ask the user for a string, count the types and numbers of letters, then output the frequency of the letters. So far I'm having an error with even getting the right input, and just can't figure out what the issue is. My (relevant) code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;    

string getPhrase(const string & phrase);  //Function for gathering string input
int main()
{
     const string phrase;
     getPhrase(phrase);
     ...
}

string getPhrase(const string &phrase)
{
   cout<<"Enter phrase: "
   getline(cin, phrase);

   return (phrase);
}
```

When I run, this I get the error:

```
freq.cpp: In function ‘std::string getPhrase(const std::string&)’:
freq.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::istream&, const
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)’
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, and just can't seem to find anything online that's relevant to what I'm doing.

Comment: What was your reasoning for making `phrase` a `const` variable? I'd like to know so we can help you understand why it's wrong. :)

Comment: If you're a beginner, you absolutely should learn 21st-century C++ and never ever say `abusing namespace std;`. Stuffy pseudo-professors in the 1980s came up with that, but that doesn't mean it's acceptable.

Comment: @sftrabbit Its a template given to me by my intro C++ class haha, I removed the "const" part and used some "std::"'s in certain places like suggested below and its finally working

Comment: @KerrekSB its an intro C++ class, and its just the way I'm being taught right now

Answer (score 1):

Your `getPhrase` should look like this:

```
std::string getPhrase()
{
    std::string result;
    std::cout << "Enter phrase: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, result);
    return result;
}
```

Then:

```
int main()
{
    std::string phrase = getPhrase();

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const string phrase;
```

remove `const` in function parameter and local variable declaration since otherwise you can't accept user input to a `const` variable, which means nonchangable/ non-modifiable.

Like the following:

```
string getPhrase(string & phrase);  //Function for gathering string input
int main()
{
     string phrase;
     getPhrase(phrase);
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `phrase` is a `const string`. That means it's constant and can't be modified. Therefore you can't use `getline` to set `phrase` to the user's input.

You should declare `phrase` with `string phrase;` and then make the parameter of `getPhrase` a non-`const` reference.

```
string getPhrase(string& phrase);  //Function for gathering string input
int main()
{
     string phrase;
     getPhrase(phrase);
     ...
}
```